WordPress bulk media import using CLI - how to retain folder structure?
I'm trying to upload or register (the files are in the Upload directory via FTP) around 2000 media files. These are organised by month and year.
Although I've not had any luck with the usual plugins that are suggested for this, I've managed to use the CLI, but everything gets put in a 'July 2024' folder (in WordPress - the underlying directory structure is, of course, unchanged).
I've used the following CLI commands:
wp media import ~/public_html/2024/wp-content/uploads/Archive/*/**\/*.jpg

find /tmp -name '*.jpg' -or -name ‘*.jpeg’ -or -name ‘*.png’| xarg wp media import

wp media regenerate —all

This imports images I've uploaded by FTP, but registers them all in 'July 2024', rather than in the month/year heirarchy of the folders in which they exist.

I was just struggling with this exact question! The best I could do was to create an unnecessary post, attach the media to the post,then delete the original post. It's possible that the post update of the date of the media attachment is unnecessary.
postid=$( wp post create --post_type=post --post_status=publish --porcelain --post_title="$mytitle"  --post_date_gmt="$mydate" )
        
#media import of the imagefile and attach it to the post as the featured image, puts in proper directory
mediaid=$( wp media import "$myimg" --post_id="$postid" --post_name="$mytitle" --title="$mytitle" --alt="$mytitle"  --featured_image --porcelain )
    
#delete the post
wp post delete $postid

#set the date on the media post 
wp post update "$mediaid" --post_date="$mydate" --post_date_gmt="$mydate"

